# Close Primeng's ModalBox when clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, primeng

I am reviewing the Primeng documentation for the Modals, but I can not find a way to programmatically close a Modal Box (Example, when I click the "accept" button).

source: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown on the documentation,  the `<p-dialog>` component has a `[(visible)]` property. It's two-binding, so you can actually close (or hide) the element by setting the aforementioned property's value to **false**. Example:

```
<p-dialog header="Foo" [(visible)]="showDialog">
  <p-footer>
    <button type="button" (click)="functionToCloseDialog()" label="Accept"></button>
  </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

And your ts file will have something like:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  showDialog: boolean;

  functionToCloseDialog() {
    this.showDialog = false; // closes/hides the dialog box
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now you dont need to use hide and show. You need to include DynamicDialogRef service for example:

```
 constructor(private ref: DynamicDialogRef) {}

 closeModal(): void {
    this.ref.close();
 }

 closeModalWithData(): void {
   // you can pass data like this
   this.ref.close(data)
   // and catch it after with onClose event
 }
```